# Is it possible in Unicode Inno Setup to call a function (code) and return a value (string) in the "Run Section"?

Tags: function, inno-setup

Under the `[Run]` section in the Inno Setup script I have the following...

```
[Run]
Filename: "{sys}\cscript.exe"; \
  Parameters: """{tmp}\myScript.vbs"" ""{code:GetStringValue}"" {#CONST_PORT}"; \
  Description: "Setting the port to {#CONST_PORT}."; \
  StatusMsg: "Setting the port to {#CONST_PORT}."; \ 
  Tasks: SetPorts; \
  Check: SetPort({#CONST_PORT}); \
  Flags: runhidden;
```

Then in the `[Code]` section I have the following...

```pascal
[Code]
function GetStringValue: String;
var
  version: Integer;
begin
  version := 20;
  result := 'This is a test showing the int ' + IntToStr(version);
end;
```

The object is to have a function that will return a string in the `[Run]` section.  Currently from everything I can tell if using `{code:}` in the `[Run]` section you are required to call a function that **only** returns a `Boolean` value.  Is there a way around this?  I need to be able to get a dynamic string to pass to my VBScript in the `[Run]` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently from everything I can tell if using `{code:}` in the `[Run]` section you are required to call a function that **only** returns a `Boolean` value.

That's not true.

Quoting the documentation on [Scripted constants](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants):

> The called function must have 1 String parameter named `Param`, and **must return a String or a Boolean value depending on where the constant is used**.

In general, when the scripted (`code:`) constant is used in the `Check` parameter, it must return a Boolean. Everywhere else (as far as I can tell), it must return a String.

---

So your script is correct, except that you are missing the parameter (it's mandatory, even if you actually do not need/use it):

```pascal
[Code]
function GetStringValue(Param: string): string;
...
```

Comment: To use the function in the `[Run]` section use something like `{code:GetStringValue|null}`.

Comment: No need for the `|null`. Just use `{code:GetStringValue}` - See the [documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants).

Comment: Ahh ok good to know.  I was reading your answer as that was part of the "mandatory" part as well.  ;)